# 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, key

I'm trying to output a dictionary to a csv. I pass in a dictionary, and I want one set of key and value on each line. I also want a header, so I'm using this code:

```
def writecsv(filename, dict):
    keylist=['Word','Number']
    with open (filename, 'w') as file:
        outfile=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=keylist)
        outfile.writeheader()
        for k,v in dict.items():
            ka=[k,v]
            outfile.writerow(ka)
```

However, it just says 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'.

How can I get this working?

Comment: don't pass a list to the `DictWriter` object... or use a regular `csv.writer` object instead if you do want to do it that way

Comment: so even just `writer = csv.writer(file); writer.writerow(keylist); writer.writerows(dict.items())`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `csv.DictWriter`, you can use this example:

```
import csv


def writecsv(filename, dct):
    keylist = ["Word", "Number"]
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        outfile = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=keylist)
        outfile.writeheader()
        for k, v in dct.items():
            outfile.writerow({"Word": k, "Number": v})


writecsv("data.csv", {"xxx": 1, "yyy": 2})
```

Creates `data.csv`:

```
Word,Number
xxx,1
yyy,2
```